# Need Example of Poor Encapsulation

Tags: java

I want to see an example of reaching directly into the code from a class that uses publicly declared data members to see an example of poor encapsulation so I can understand the good examples of encapsulation in OOP by contrasting with a bad example.(Being told to use encapsulation without a bad example is like being told not to steal without understanding what stealing is to me.) Thanks.

Comment: `System.out.println()` and `System.setOut(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a `Counter` class that:

1. Starts with value = 0
2. Lets you increase the value by one (`increment`)
3. Lets you see the current value

A poorly-encapsulated version would directly expose the inner counter value:

```
class Counter {
    public int value;

    public Counter() {
        this.value = 0;
    }

    public int increment() {
        return ++this.value;
    }
}
```

The problem, of course, is that users of the class can do this:

```
Counter c = new Counter();
System.out.println(c.value); // 0
c.increment();
System.out.println(c.value); // 1
c.value = 42;
System.out.println(c.value); // 42
```

Proper encapsulation corrects that:

```
class Counter {
    private int value;         // *** Private

    public Counter() {
        this.value = 0;
    }

    public int increment() {
        return ++this.value;
    }

    public int getValue() {    // *** Accessor
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Now, there's no way¹ for the user of the class to directly set `value`.

```
Counter c = new Counter();
System.out.println(c.getValue()); // 0
c.increment();
System.out.println(c.getValue()); // 1
// No equivalent to `c.value = 42` is possible here¹
```

---

¹ *(without using reflection)*

Comment: All good and well, but given that the OP seems to be beginner, why not answer why we don't want people to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a useful one, since understanding the reasons that encapsulation is important will help you avoid overgeneralizing the principle as well as help you understand when you've done it adequately.

You can find an example of poor encapsulation here: https://github.com/dotnet/training-tutorials/blob/master/content/csharp/getting-started/encapsulation-oop.md When the class in the example is used by other code to do something mundane, it create problems because the class hasn't been encapsulated. (Other examples might illustrate the problems that are created by *poor* encapsulation rather than a *lack* of encapsulation, but I understand you to want an example of the basic idea.)

Many times the problem that is created by not encapsulating your code is that properties and/or objects are updated or deleted when it is a *copy* of the object that you actually wish to update or delete.

Here are some relevant portions of the linked example. The first quote describes the problem that is created when the class lacks encapsulation:

> Notice that in this example, the technique used to print the orders is a while loop that throws away each record as it prints it. This is an implementation detail, and if the collection this loop was working with were properly encapsulated, it wouldn't cause any issues. Unfortunately, even though a locally scoped orders variable is used to represent the collection, the calls to RemoveAt are actually removing records from the underlying Customer object. At the end of the program, both customers have 0 orders. This is not the intended behavior.

The second quote notes that the problem can be "solved" with a different implementation, but avoided altogether with encapsulation:

> There are a variety of ways this can be addressed, the simplest of which is to change the while loop to a foreach, but the underlying problem is that Customer isn't encapsulating its Orders property in any way. Even if it didn't allow other classes to set the property, the List type it exposes is itself breaking encapsulation, and allowing collaborators to arbitrarily Remove or even Clear the contents of the collection.

What this example illustrates well is that the need for encapsulation isn't absolute, but it's most certainly a best practice.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! But link-only answers aren't considered answers here, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for details.

Comment: Thanks, TJ. I've been editing my response to add detail and explanation.

Comment: Please do that *before* clicking Post Your Answer, rather than after.

Comment: Got it. I hadn't been aware of the meta post at the time, but I'll use that as my standard from now on.